# How to run a batch file to backup to VPN drive?

Tags: windows, batch

I have a VPN into a client and I want schedule a batch file that will do some file copying
to backup some data.

Problem is how do I automate to connect to the VPN if not connected
and also unless I have accessed the mapped drive in explorer the batch file says can't find
drive.

So I need to automate:

1. Connect to VPN
2. Make sure access to mapped drive ok
3. Schedule batch file

Malcolm

EDIT: I am using the builtin VPN client for Windows Vista.

Comment: It would help if you would explain the type of VPN you are using.

Answer (score 2):

What VPN client are you using? How to automate it would depend on what system you are using.

As for automating the network drive connection you could use something similar to the following:

```
NET USE X: \\192.168.1.2\sharename password /user:someuser
```

Just replace the details appropriately:

- Replace X with whatever letter you want to map to
- Change the IP address obviously ;-)
- Replace sharename with whatever share you're wanting to backup to

You can leave off password and /user if you are connecting to an unprotected share.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am using the builtin Windows Vista VPN, does that help?

Comment: Use the command "rasdial" to start the connection to the VPN.